# How to add build steps to Eclipse "run configuration"?

Tags: eclipse, build-process, applet

Is there a way to add build steps to a "run configuration" in Eclipse?

My project uses an applet that should be built before starting the web application. So I'd like to configure Eclipse to do this single step before actually running the application.

I know I can do it with Ant/Maven, but I wonder if there's a way to do it in Eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a classic launching (Java or Java Applet) configuration, no. Not directly.

For an External Tols launcher, not directly either.

The idea would be:

- to not build your applet every time you modify your main project
- make sure it is built when you want to launch your webapp.

For that, you could define two projects:

- one for the compilation of your main project.
- the second (depending on the first) for the compilation of your applet.

Your launching configuration would then run with the second project (which includes the first)

If the option "Build automatically" is selected, the second project shouldn't run without being compiled first.